# Activation digest isn't saving to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

To create a confirmation link for users who want to update their email address, a users controller method calls on the model method `@user.send_activation_email`. The relevant part of the controller method:

```
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    puts "DIGEST1: #{@user.activation_digest}"
    @user.send_activation_email
    puts "DIGEST2: #{@user.activation_digest}"
    puts "DIGEST2_RELOAD (should be same as previous but isn't): #{@user.reload.activation_digest}"
```

The model method reads:

```
  def send_activation_email
    create_activation_digest
    update_columns(activation_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
    UserMailer.new_email_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  private
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
```

The private method is also used for account activation. There is saves the digest automatically to the `activation_digest` column. This doesn't however seem to work for the above. That is, while it generates a new digest, it does not save that value to the db (I know this by using `puts` for that value in the controller method before and after calling the model method).

**Why is it not saving the digest value to the db?** I've tried adding `update_columns(activation_sent_at: Time.zone.now, activation_digest: self.activation_digest)` to the model method. But that didn't save the value either (and it doesn't seem secure to me).

Comment: Could you explain? Doesn't `update_columns(activation_sent_at: Time.zone.now, activation_digest: self.activation_digest)` commit? That is, shouldn't that commit/write the value to the db?

Comment: `update_columns` is a direct write to the db and has no call backs. If you actually had the above line (in the comment) in the file it would update the record but you might have to call reload to see it. As of right now you are not actually persisting the data but simply setting instance attributes that are discarded with the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the DB is not updated is because you're not saving the model.

Either add save! at the end of the private method or use update_attributes() query, which automatically saves the values to DB.

Comment: Yes, if I added `update_attribute(:activation_digest, self.activation_digest)` to `def send_activation_email` instead of `update_columns` it worked.